# Transfer function block diagram

Tags: discrete-signals, homework, transfer-function

Can any one help with the $y[n]$ and $x[n]$ relationship in this block diagram, I just keep have a $t[n]$ in my answer that I can't get rid off.

On my best try I got to $y[n] = 2t[n]-x[n-1]-y[n-2]+x[n]$

If you could also tell me how you got there it would be great.

Thanks anyone for help.[image]

Comment: Are you allowed to use the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform?

Comment: that unit-delay element in the middle is not legit.  the two outputs are the same and it should be drawn that way explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to solve such problems using the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform. First, write down the time domain equations:

$$\begin{align}\tag{1}
y[n]&=r[n]+x[n]\\
r[n]&=r[n-1]+t[n]+t[n-1]\\
t[n]&=t[n-1]+y[n-1]+y[n-2]
\end{align}$$

Taking the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of these equations gives

$$\begin{align}\tag{2}
Y(z)&=R(z)+X(z)\\
R(z)&=z^{-1}R(z)+T(z)+z^{-1}T(z)\\
T(z)&=z^{-1}T(z)+z^{-1}Y(z)+z^{-2}Y(z)
\end{align}$$

After simplification you get

$$\begin{align}
R(z)&=T(z)\frac{1+z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}\\
T(z)&=Y(z)z^{-1}\frac{1+z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

from which

$$R(z)=Y(z)z^{-1}\frac{(1+z^{-1})^2}{(1-z^{-1})^2}\tag{3}$$

follows.
Plugging (3) into the first equation of (2) gives

$$Y(z)=Y(z)z^{-1}\frac{(1+z^{-1})^2}{(1-z^{-1})^2}+X(z)\tag{4}$$

from which you finally obtain afters some algebra

$$H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{(1-z^{-1})^2}{1-3z^{-1}-z^{-2}-z^{-3}}\tag{5}$$

In the time domain, Eq. (5) is equivalent to

$$y[n]-3y[n-1]-y[n-2]-y[n-3]=x[n]-2x[n-1]+x[n-2]\tag{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

Two general suggestions:
1-Systematically write the equations at each node.
2-Time index can be changed to get new equations. For example in the top left node we have:
$$r[n]=y[n]-x[n]$$,
and thus:
$$r[n-1]=y[n-1]-x[n-1]$$.

Answer:
Write the equations at the two other nodes:
$$t[n]-t[n-1]=y[n-1]+y[n-2](*)$$
$$t[n]+t[n-1]=r[n]-r[n-1]=y[n]-x[n]-y[n-1]+x[n-1] $$ 
Add two equations together:
$$t[n]=\frac{y[n]+y[n-2]-x[n]+x[n-1]}{2}$$
change n to n-1
$$t[n-1]=\frac{y[n-1]+y[n-3]-x[n-1]+x[n-2]}{2}$$
replace $t[n]$ and $t[n-1]$ in (*)

$$y[n-1]+y[n-2]=-\frac{y[n-1]+y[n-3]-x[n-1]+x[n-2]}{2}+\frac{y[n]+y[n-2]-x[n]+x[n-1]}{2}$$
simplify....

Or you can use Z transform as above which gives a more compact solution.

Comment: Your last equation is wrong. The easiest way to get the correct result is to plug the expressions for $t[n]$ and $t[n-1]$ into the equation *above* the starred one. If you do this you obtain the same result as I do. Basically, it's just the plus sign before the last term in your final equation which should be a minus sign.